# Page Numbering in pdf file created wkhtmltopdf in php

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, page-numbering

I need to create pdf file from php using wkhtmltopdf with page numbers
I am using table inside the php file,tried some codes in javascript, that showing only on the last page if set in footer or in first page if setting in header, not getting page number
how can i use that

my sample code is :

```js
function substitutePdfVariables() {

            function getParameterByName(name) {
                var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
                return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }

            function substitute(name) {
                var value = getParameterByName(name);
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(name);

                for (var i = 0; elements && i < elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].textContent = value;
                }
            }

            ['frompage', 'topage', 'page', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'subsubsection']
                .forEach(function(param) {
                    substitute(param);
                });
        }
```

```html
<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Head 1</th><th>Head 2</th><th>Head 3</th><th>Head 4</th><th>Head 5</th></tr></thead><tbody>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td><td>Data 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td><td>Data 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td><td>Data 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td><td>Data 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td><td>Data 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td><td>Data 5</td></tr></tbody></table>
<body onload="substitutePdfVariables()">
    <p>Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the JavaScript page numbering to work, it should be placed in a header or footer template supplied to the `wkhtmltopdf` command so that it gets repeated on every page.

From the [wkhtmltopdf documentation](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt):

```
Headers and footers can also be supplied with HTML documents. As an example
one could specify `--header-html header.html`, and use the following content in
header.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><script>
function subst() {
    var vars = {};
    var query_strings_from_url = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for (var query_string in query_strings_from_url) {
        if (query_strings_from_url.hasOwnProperty(query_string)) {
            var temp_var = query_strings_from_url[query_string].split('=', 2);
            vars[temp_var[0]] = decodeURI(temp_var[1]);
        }
    }
    var css_selector_classes = ['page', 'frompage', 'topage', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'date', 'isodate', 'time', 'title', 'doctitle', 'sitepage', 'sitepages'];
    for (var css_class in css_selector_classes) {
        if (css_selector_classes.hasOwnProperty(css_class)) {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName(css_selector_classes[css_class]);
            for (var j = 0; j < element.length; ++j) {
                element[j].textContent = vars[css_selector_classes[css_class]];
            }
        }
    }
}
</script></head><body style="border:0; margin: 0;" onload="subst()">
<table style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
    <tr>
    <td class="section"></td>
    <td style="text-align:right">
        Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body></html>


As can be seen from the example, the arguments are sent to the header/footer
html documents in get fashion.
```

Comment: Thanks for underlying the "should be placed in a header or footer template"! I was missing that for days.